# Updating large binary files

Tags: c#, file-io, io, large-files

Thera a number of large binary files (>1Gb each) that need to be partially updated with no length changes. How do I update it as fast as possible? Looks like they're being buffered prior saving to disk when I use standard FileStream call. Would like to set certain bytes directly on file system.
Thanks.

Comment: I would use the same algorithm that Google uses for Chrome.

Comment: What is unclean in the question? There is a huge file. I need to set some byte value in a middle of it. I dont wanna OS to buffer all billions bytes to make this operation.